# Use native private fields and methods with Typescript and ES5

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to use a library that internally uses private fields such as `#fieldName: any`, by keeping my `ES5` target.

When I try to transpile, I get: `Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher`.

The only way to solve this is either target `ES6` or higher, or put `skipLibCheck`as false.

Is it possible to avoid doing this? Maybe through other tools such as Babel?

Comment: Maybe with a WeakMap polyfill...

Comment: Are you transpiling using `tsc` or using `babel`?

Comment: I am transpiling using tsc (for now) @Bergi

Comment: @EuberDeveloper Then either target ES6 or use babel instead. As the error message says, tsc does not support transpiling modern features to old syntax (and really it's not the tool for that job).

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a superset transpiler to vanilla JS. Babel is a JavaScript Next to JavaScript transpiler. I believe it is possible to transpile from TS to ES6 then have Babel pick it up from there and transpile into ES5. The setup might be a bit tricky but definitely achievable.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so what you mean is that while Typescript has not implemented any "polyfill" for the # fields in ES5, Babel did? If yes, would you share a basic configuration code?

Comment: Babel can parse and transpile TypeScript source code directly (it just doesn't do any typechecking), you should not chain `tsc` with `babel`.

Comment: @Bergi I was not aware Babel can transpile TS without any typechecking. Thank you for this.